# C# MVC3 JQuery Controls Not Working On First Load (but works on second load)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm currently working on some internal project where user will upload a .csv file to the database & run his analysis. I'm using C# MVC3 for this. This particular task involves 1 controller for actions and 2 views. The first view(1) is a default page where the user will be asked to upload file. Once the file is successfully uploaded to the server the controller returns a 'success' message to user on the same view. (along with the message a new button named 'Analyze' will be shown to user to run his further analysis.) Once the user clicks the Analyze button the call goes to controller & collects some lookup data based on the file he uploaded & returns to second view(2).

**"Here is the problem i'm facing, once the user is landed on second view i'm displaying some pre-populated form fields with a dropdownlist-1. The dropdownlist-1 has a JQuery function '.change' - basically this function makes a ajax post call to get the a list of values & populates another dropdownlist-2 based on user selection (*which is not working on first attempt*). If the user go back to main menu & try to *re-upload* the same file, the same controller action checks if the file exists on the server by file name, since the earlier upload was successful it immediately redirects him to view(2) instead of overwriting. Now the JQuery functionality/controls working as expected for the same dropdownlist-1. The only difference I have noticed is on the first attempt the file upload takes few seconds because its uploading to the server & during the second attempt the file is already uploaded to the server it immediately returns to the view2 (where all controls are working as expected on second attempt)"**

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything here since it always works on second attempt & never on first attempt(note: second attempt works only if the user upload the same file, if the user changes the file in second attempt then again same issue). I have added few buttons in the form to see if the submit action is working but no, none of the controls working in first attempt.

appreciate any guidance on this. I can post the sample code if anyone would like to check,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's my bad ... after breaking my head i have found that one of parameters I'm passing to Jquery control is invalid on first load. I have taken care of this and it works like a charm.